# WP 8.1 xbox music styled pivot

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Does anyone know to make a pivot behave like it does in xbox music for windows phone? With the large title that slides along with the background image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the music app they use a control called Hub, you can find information about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.hub.aspx